# Why is the number of industries on the SO developer story capped?

Tags: discussion, developer-story, stack-overflow-jobs

I was prompted to update my Developer Story, and as I was looking through the industries list, there are quite a few that would be applicable.

Why is there a limit to the number you can select here?

Doesn't this limit the visibility of your developer story to prospective recruiters and hiring companies?

It would seem like the Developer Story would be more useful to developers if they were able to flag all of the industries they are interested in.

Comment: #To #prevent #hashtagging #like #twitter...

Comment: I would rather put industries I'm not interested in working in, much smaller list.

Comment: @Braiam - valid.

Comment: @Gimby - agreed, that would be a better approach for some of us.